# An unknown space shown in the body Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know what exactly the problem is, but I am aware that I can just use `overflow-x: hidden;`, but I want a proper solution to this issue.

```
<style>
.sidebar{
    height: 500px;
    border: thin black solid;

}

.nav_menu{
    border: thin red solid;
}

.content{
    border: thin green solid;
    height: 430px;
}



</style>



<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
    Your side bar content
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav_menu">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin:0;">
        <div class="col-md-12 content">
            Your Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Maybe the problem is related to using the `.row` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of the classes- 
the container is the parent - the row classes sit inside that and the col-X sit inside the row.

In bootstrap world - the container class has styling to limit the content to a max of 1200px and to center it (use .container-fluid) if you want a full width container).

The div with a class of .row - applies  a negative 15px margin left and right - this is to ensure that the content of the divs sit flush to the left and right. 
The column divs have a padding of 15 px left and right and this padding collectively makes the 'gutters' between column content (and if the .row class did not have the -15 margin - there would be 15px to the left of the first column acontent and 15px to the right of the last column content.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
     content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 main-content">
     content
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: no this will not solve it, this will make a padding from the right and left.

Comment: read my answer - sorry was typing while you posted - the .row has the negative margin left and right to remove the left and right padding of the first and last columns.

Comment: sorry* yes it's solved now, I should use just like what you said, I should use .container-fluid, I'm sorry for the last comment, I didn't read your full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code structure to

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
     Your side bar content
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9">
    // Your Content
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```